# Magento 2 How can we associate a single template with multiple view models?

Tags: magento2, overrides, viewmodel

I want to associate another custom view model with a template. The template already has a view model in the core file. Can I associate an other custom view model with this template?

Comment: Show your layout xml

Answer (score 1):

To use multiple view models in a single template, you can pass each view model class as an argument to a template's block in the page layout configuration file, then you can use these view models in this template as you did for a single view model.

Example:
In the following example snippet, `MyNewViewModel` and `ItemsToRender` are view model classes of the `ExampleCorp_Catalog` module passed as an argument to a block:

```
<block name="examplecorp.new.viewmodel" template="ExampleCorp_Catalog::example.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel\MyNewViewModel</argument>
        <argument name="itemsToRenderViewModel" xsi:type="object">ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel\ItemsToRender</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

The view model class must always implement the interface `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface`. For example:

```
<?php
namespace ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel;

class itemsToRenderViewModel implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
      return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

```
<?php
namespace ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel;

class ItemsToRender implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getItems()
    {
      return 'List of items should be defined here';
    }
}
```

You can access the public methods for view model classes in the template:

```
<?php
/** @var \ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel\MyNewViewModel $viewModel */
/** @var \ExampleCorp\Catalog\ViewModel\ItemsToRender $itemsToRenderViewModel */

$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
$itemsToRenderViewModel = $block->getData('itemsToRenderViewModel');

?>
<h1><?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getTitle()); ?></h1>
<?= $block->escapeHtml($itemsToRenderViewModel->getItems()); ?>
```

You can read more about View models from the official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/view-models/